# How to compute a point trend line?

Tags: qgis

I have a track of GPS position dots that are roughly going in a straight line, I would like to simplify the line to only have the central point from a group as in the bottom image creating a trend line from many points.

Is there anyway to keep attribution when going points to lines?
If not is there any way to remove points from a line of points?

In ArcGIS I can do this:
[image]

Comment: Are the points ordered somehow?

Comment: Yes they are in a chronological order, it is a vessel track.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you want to do. Maybe you could elaborate on what the pictures are supposed to tell me.

Comment: Okay, i have a track of GPS position dots that are roughly going in a straight line, I would like to simplify the line to only have the central point from a group as in the bottom image crating a trend line from many points.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "only have the central point from a group"?